# Aggregating in R

Tags: r, count, aggregate-functions

I have a data frame with two columns. I want to add an additional two columns to the data set with counts based on aggregates.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1045937900, 1045937900), 
SMS.Type = c("DF1", "WCB14"), 
SMS.Date = c("12/02/2015 19:51", "13/02/2015 08:38"), 
Reply.Date = c("", "13/02/2015 09:52")
), row.names = 4286:4287, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to simply count the number of Instances of SMS.Type and Reply.Date where there is no null. So in the toy example below, i will generate the 2 for SMS.Type and 1 for Reply.Date

I then want to add this to the data frame as total counts (Im aware they will duplicate out for the number of rows in the original dataset but thats ok)

I have been playing around with aggregate and count function but to no avail

```
mytempdf <-aggregate(cbind(testtrain$SMS.Type,testtrain$Response.option)~testtrain$ID,
                  train, 
                  function(x) length(unique(which(!is.na(x)))))

mytempdf <- aggregate(testtrain$Reply.Date~testtrain$ID,
                  testtrain, 
                  function(x) length(which(!is.na(x))))
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `data.table` you could do (I've added a real `NA` to your original data).
I'm also not sure if you really looking for `length(unique())` or just `length`?

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("SMS.Type", "Reply.Date")
setDT(df)[, paste0(cols, ".count") := 
                  lapply(.SD, function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x)))), 
                  .SDcols = cols, 
            by = ID]
#            ID SMS.Type         SMS.Date       Reply.Date SMS.Type.count Reply.Date.count
# 1: 1045937900      DF1 12/02/2015 19:51               NA              2                1
# 2: 1045937900    WCB14 13/02/2015 08:38 13/02/2015 09:52              2                1
```

In the devel version (v >= 1.9.5) you also could use `uniqueN` function

---

**Explanation**

This is a general solution which will work on any number of desired columns. All you need to do is to put the columns names into `cols`.

1. `lapply(.SD,` is calling a certain function over the columns specified in `.SDcols = cols`
2. `paste0(cols, ".count")` creates new column names while adding `count` to the column names specified in `cols`
3. `:=` performs *assignment by reference*, meaning, updates the newly created columns with the output of `lapply(.SD,` *in place*
4. `by` argument is specifying the aggregator columns

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for introducing me to data.table...Can you explain what each line is doing from the SetDT onwards if you have the time. To answer your question, i was using the length(unique()) to try and count the values uniquely in the columns

Comment: I've added explanation.

Comment: @JohnSmith, I suggest starting with the Introduction to data.table HTML vignette [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

After converting your empty strings to NAs:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, SMS.Type.count   = sum(!is.na(SMS.Type)),
           Reply.Date.count = sum(!is.na(Reply.Date)))
```