# Using Table to Group: invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Tags: r, grouping

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211704/aggregating-in-r) about how to take the contents of a column and use them as column headers in a new data-frame with a Boolean expression of 1 or 0. if it contained the value in R

An example would be

```
Id.   Event
A.    Wc
B.    Df
C.    Df
A.    Df
```

Needs to be converted to

```
     Wc df
A   1.    1
B   0.     1
C.  0.    1
```

I have since being playing around with it and it seems to work fine however recently i have been getting the following error

***Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument***

```
# get the totals by counting factors for SMS Type and number of replies 
cols <- c("SMS.Type", "Replied")
setDT(train)[, paste0(cols, ".count") := 
       lapply(.SD, function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x)))), 
     .SDcols = cols, 
     by = awb_no]


# Summerize a column and convert it to boolean column header
lst <- train$SMS.Type
lvl <- unique(unlist(lst))      
train.agg.chkpt <- data.frame(ID_no=train$ID_no,
          do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, function(x) table(factor(x,levels=lvl)))), 
          stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

train.agg.chkpt <- aggregate (train.agg.chkpt,by=list(ID_no=train.agg.chkpt$ID_no), FUN = "sum")
train.agg.chkpt <- train.agg.chkpt[c(-1)]
```

The column ID_no is just an ID number and this is the ID around which the booleans are grouped. Its a character type number (I assume this is what the error message is referencing)

Each ID should be unique. Below is the structure of the dataset

```
str(train.agg.chkpt)
'data.frame':   823462 obs. of  12 variables:
  $ ID_no  : chr  "AAAAAAA75465" "BBBBB175465" "CCCCCC75476" "DDDDD75476" ...
 $ WC      : int  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ DF1     : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DF2     : int  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ WCB14   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WCA13   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ HN      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WCB13   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WCA12   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WCA14   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WCB12   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Below is the traceback()

```
lapply(X = split(e, grp), FUN = FUN, ...)
4: FUN(X[[1L]], ...)
3: lapply(x, function(e) {
   ans <- lapply(X = split(e, grp), FUN = FUN, ...)
   if (simplify && length(len <- unique(sapply(ans, length))) == 
       1L) {
       if (len == 1L) {
           cl <- lapply(ans, oldClass)
           cl1 <- cl[[1L]]
           ans <- unlist(ans, recursive = FALSE)
           if (!is.null(cl1) && all(sapply(cl, function(x) identical(x, 
               cl1)))) 
               class(ans) <- cl1
       }
       else if (len > 1L) 
           ans <- matrix(unlist(ans, recursive = FALSE), nrow = nry, 
               ncol = len, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = {
                 if (!is.null(nms <- names(ans[[1L]]))) 
                   list(NULL, nms)
                 else NULL
               })
   }
   ans
   })
2: aggregate.data.frame(train.agg.chkpt, by = list(ID_no = train.agg.chkpt$ID_no), 
   FUN = "sum")
1: aggregate(train.agg.chkpt, by = list(ID_no = train.agg.chkpt$ID_no), 
   FUN = "sum")
```

Can anyone help me understand the error message?

Thank you for your time

Comment: What does `traceback()` say

Comment: Instead of that code, can you please show us the desired output of that code using the data in the linked question?

Comment: Hi david I have updated the question to show the end result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your desired output could be easily reached with a simple `table` implementation per each `Id`. Here's a possible `data.table` (which you already using) implementation

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.list(table(Event)), by = Id]
#    Id Df Wc
# 1:  A  1  1
# 2:  B  1  0
# 3:  C  1  0
```

Or alternatively, (as suggested) you could use a simple `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(df), Id ~ Event, fun = length, value.var = "Event")
#    Id Df Wc
# 1:  A  1  1
# 2:  B  1  0
# 3:  C  1  0
```

Or similarly

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Id ~ Event, fun = length, value.var = "Event")
```

Or using `tidyr` (**See *Note* below**)

```
library(tidyr)
df$indx <- 1
spread(df, Event, indx, fill = 0) 
#   Id Df Wc
# 1  A  1  1
# 2  B  1  0
# 3  C  1  0
```

Or using `reshape` from base R (**See *Note* below**)

```
reshape(df, idvar = "Id", timevar = "Event", direction = "wide", v.names = "indx")
#   Id indx.Wc indx.Df
# 1  A       1       1
# 2  B      NA       1
# 3  C      NA       1
```

---

- ***Note*** `spread` and `reshape` won't work here in case same `Id` has same `Event` more than once because they don't have the `fun.aggregate` argument, so they won't know how to handle it.

---

**Benchmarks**

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e7
df <- data.frame(Id = sample(LETTERS, n, replace  = TRUE),
                 Event = sample(outer(LETTERS, letters, paste0), n, replace = TRUE))
dt <- copy(df)

DT1 <- function(x) setDT(x)[, as.list(table(Event)), by = Id]
DT2 <- function(x) dcast.data.table(setDT(x), Id ~ Event, fun = length, value.var = "Event")
RESHAPE2 <- function(x) dcast(x, Id ~ Event, fun = length, value.var = "Event")

microbenchmark(DT1(dt), DT2(dt), RESHAPE2(df))
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#      DT1(dt)  965.5181  987.8140 1017.8237 1007.1197 1030.7272 1285.9206   100
#      DT2(dt)  406.7124  420.6203  446.8026  434.2489  455.4364  592.4333   100
# RESHAPE2(df) 2969.0057 3035.5817 3190.6514 3099.3221 3240.4642 4384.6316   100
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much David for this answer and your original